# Tableau calculated field to subtract x hours

Tags: datetime, tableau-api

I have the calculated field which takes a millisecond formatted time and converts it into a standard date - my question is its in GMT time - how do I subtract 5 HOURS off of this?

```
makedate(1970,1,1)+(int([last update dttm (FIELD NAME)]/1000))/(60*60*24)
```

Comment: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_date.html  Use dateadd with a negative interval

Answer (score 2):

This should work: `dateadd('hour',-5,[date_field])`

Comment: Or better yet, maybe there’s a way to automatically use the proper calculation to “local time” based on system time? Or maybe tableau isn’t that smart :)??

Comment: I wrote about that in a past. It's possible. http://dataknightrises.com/2014/10/01/tableau-utc-conversion/